# GWT-SuggestBox as a TextBox?

Tags: java, gwt, textbox, suggestbox

I currently have a GWT textbox class that I would like to use, and sometimes based on certain parameters, transform it(add the functionality) into a suggestbox. Is this possible?

I don't want to create a new type of widget because then i would loose all of the current functionality of my TextBox, which I only wish to add the feature of suggestbox too...sometimes.

Assuming this is possible how would I link the two together? I obviously cant just do:

```
myTextBox.add(mySuggestBox);
```

I realize I appear as a novice here, and I can assure you, that is the case :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enhance any existing `ValueBox<String>` (note that `TextBox` extends it) with a `SuggestBox`, just use the appropriate constructor:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
MultiWordSuggestOracle oracle = new MultiWordSuggestOracle();

SuggestBox suggestBox = new SuggestBox(oracle, textBox);
```

Any handler previously added to the text box will work.